# Are all theorems of minimal arithmetic theorems of a given theory?

Tags: logic, model-theory, meta-math

I am working on some metamathematics revision and the following question came up. Let the theory $R_0$ be axiomatized by the following axiom schemata which hold for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$:

1. $\overline{m}+\overline{n} = \overline{m+n}$
2. $\overline{m}\cdot\overline{n} = \overline{m\cdot n}$
3. if $m<n$, then $\exists x \text{ } sx + \overline{m} = \overline{n}$
4. if $m\neq n$, then $\neg \overline{m} = \overline{n}$

($\overline{m}$ is a shorthand that abbreviates 0 prefixed my $m$ occurences of s)

Now take the theory $Q_0$ (which is a *variant* of minimal arithmetic -- note the absence of Ax. 3 of Robinson Arithmetic) axiomatized by:

1. $\forall x \neg 0 = sx$
2. $\forall x \forall y (sx=sy \rightarrow x=y)$
3. $\forall x + 0 = x$
4. $\forall x \forall y x+sy = s(x+y)$
5. $\forall x \cdot 0 = 0$
6. $\forall x \forall y x\cdot sy = (x\cdot y) +x$

Are all theorems of $Q_0$ theorems of $R_0$?

I'd be grateful for any pointers as to how to go about answering this kind of questions as well as full solutions. I am currently trying to derive the axioms of $Q_0$ as theorems of $R_0$ - is that the correct way forward?

Thanks for your help!

Best wishes,

Leon

Comment: What is the "Ax. 3 of Robinson Arithmetic" you speak about? I don't think there's a canonical numbering of them (and even if there is, it would be easier for you to tell us what it is rather than expect us to dig up a reference to find it out).

Comment: Note that every instance of _your_ axiom 3 is implied by the appropriate instance of your axiom 1.

Comment: I'm using the numbering from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic -- but I list all the axioms that I am using. The one that is not part of my list is $y=0 \vee \exists x sx = y$. I hope that helps.

Comment: Are you referring to my ax3 of $Q_0$ or $R_0$? For $R_0$, I cannot see this being true: surely Ax1 only implies the existence of some number, not necessarily positive?

Comment: Your axiom 3 of $R_0$ is implied by your axiom 1 of $R_0$. For example one instance of your axiom 3 says $\exists x.sx+\overline{10}=\overline{20}$. However the existence of such an $x$ follows from the axiom $\overline{10}+\overline{10}=\overline{20}$ -- remember that $\overline{10}$ is an abbreviation of $s(\overline{9})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the interpretation with the domain $\mathbb N\cup \{*\}$ and the usual operations on naturals, extended with
$$ s({*})=0 $$
$$ {*}+n = n+{*} = {*}+{*} =  {*}\cdot n = n\cdot{*} = {*}\cdot{*} = {*} $$

This is a model of $R_0$ but not of $Q_0$ (it fails the first axiom). Therefore the axioms of $Q_0$ are not all theorems of $R_0$.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers!